# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str Python/django

Tags: python, mysql, django, cursor

I'm having an error with this:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT username as username, sum(ACCTSESSIONTIME) as total_acctsessiontime FROM RADUSAGE GROUP BY username LIMIT 0, 10")

usage_summary = cursor.fetchall()

for row in usage_summary:
    row['total_acctsessiontime'] = 0 if row['total_acctsessiontime'] is None else humanize_seconds(row['total_acctsessiontime'])
    row['total_acctinputoctets'] = 0 if row['total_acctinputoctets'] is None else naturalsize(row['total_acctinputoctets'])
    row['total_acctoutputoctets'] = 0 if row['total_acctoutputoctets'] is None else naturalsize(row['total_acctoutputoctets'])

return jsonify(cursor)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/loc_rad/admin_app/dashboard.py", line 57, in inquiry
row['total_acctsessiontime'] = 0 if row['total_acctsessiontime'] is None else humanize_seconds(row['total_acctsessiontime'])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

This is my first time to use the cursor connection. I hope someone could help me with this.

Comment: As the error says, `row` is a tuple, not a dict.

Comment: cursor.fetchAll returns you a tuple. Why are trying to access it as a dict

Comment: You can't use `jsonify(cursor)`

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.fetchall()` returned tuple. In your case this tuple will be so:
`(('username1', 100), ('username2', 200),)`

for using this method `row['total_acctsessiontime']` you should create dict every time in the loop, or do so

```
items = {'username': 0, 'total_acctoutputoctets': 1}
for row in usage_summary:
    row[item['total_acctsessiontime']] = 0 if row[item['total_acctsessiontime']] is None else humanize_seconds(row[item['total_acctsessiontime']])
```

But easy way is:

```
for row in usage_summary:
    row[1] = 0 if row[1] is None else humanize_seconds(row[1])
```

**UPDATE1**

```
acctsessiontime, acctoutputoctets, acctinputoctets == [], [], []
for row in usage_summary:
    acctsessiontime.append(0 if row[1] is None else humanize_seconds(row[1]))
    acctoutputoctets.append(0 if row[1] is None else humanize_seconds(row[1]))
    acctinputoctets.append(0 if row[1] is None else humanize_seconds(row[1]))
all_sum = sum(acctsessiontime) + sum(acctoutputoctets) + sum(acctinputoctets)
```

Comment: I tried this but I still got this: TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Yes, because tuple is immutable. You can't change it. For solve, it needs to use list

Comment: Can you give more info about what do you want to get in the end?

Comment: I need to get the sum of total_acctsessiontime, total_acctinputoctets and total_acctoutputoctets and convert it. That's why I used the humanize_seconds and naturalsize.

Comment: I updated my answer. But it's a different task. And here will be error, because you selected 2 variable but want to use 3